# Variable scope problems in unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme

My test of a react component looks like this (based off [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/the-right-way-to-test-react-components-548a4736ab22)):

```
// MyComponent.test.js


import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.jsx';

describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
  let props;
  let state;
  let mountedComponent;

  // The problematic part to be changed
  const component = () => {
    if (!mountedComponent) {
      // This enzyme mount is actually much more complex, 
      // as I'm wrapping all sorts of contexts and globals around it
      // which is why I want to take this function outside,
      // and use it as boilerplate in every test
      mountedComponent = mount(<MyComponent {...props} />);
    }
    return mountedComponent;
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {};
    state = {};
    mountedComponent = undefined;
  });

  it('Works', () => {
    state = { val: true };
    component().setState(state,
      () => expect(component().state('val')).to.equal(true),
    );
  });
});
```

This works well, the `component()` function properly returns the same `mountedComponent` if called multiple times in the same `it`, as the current value of mountedComponent is preserved between calls, and only resets beforeEach test.

Now if I extract the `component()` function outside this test to another file:

```
// getMountedComponent.js

const getMountedComponent = (AnyComponent, props, mountedComponent) => {

  if (!mountedComponent) {
    // Appears not to properly reassign mountedComponent
    mountedComponent = mount(<AnyComponent {...props} />);
  }
  return mountedComponent;
};
```

And replace the `component()` function with this:

```
// MyComponent.test.js

// Cleaner problematic part
const component = () => getMountedComponent(MyComponent, props, mountedComponent);
```

Then this this test fails, because component() returns a fresh component the second time, with state = null.

It appears to be a scope issue, but I can't wrap my head around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `getMountedComponent` function accepts `mountedComponent` argument - actually it creates new `mountedComponent` variable inside this function so it overrides variable with the same name defined in `describle` block. So every time you call `getMountedComponent` it creates new local variable and as a result you never assign any value to `mountedComponent` variable defined in `describe` scope. To fix it you can cache component on function itself (functions are first-class objects in JS) insetad of using external variable:

```
function getMountedComponent(MyComponent, props) {

  if (!getMountedComponent.mountedComponent) {
    // Appears not to properly reassign mountedComponent
    getMountedComponent.mountedComponent = mount(<MyComponent {...props} />);
  }
  return getMountedComponent.mountedComponent;
};
```

To clear function cache just use this:

```
delete getMountedComponent.mountedComponent;
```

Comment: The reason I'm pulling the function out of the describe function, is because it is actually a bit more complex than what I explained. Which means I want the `getMountedComponent` to live in another file.

Comment: Beautiful ! It worked :)
I immediately used this to write a function: `getMountedComponent.reset = () => { delete getMountedComponent.mountedComponent; }`

Comment: Great :) Yes, adding a method to clear cache is very good idea :)

Answer (score 0):

[Javascript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

> Javascript is always pass by value, but when a variable refers to an
>   object (including arrays), the "value" is a reference to the object.

When you've taken the `getMountedComponent` function outside, you are no longer setting the `mountedComponent` variable in your `describe` function and therefore leaves it `undefined`, so it will create a new copy of the `mountedComponent` everytime.

```
const getMountedComponent = (MyComponent, props, mountedComponent) => {

  if (!mountedComponent) {
    // You are not changing the "mountedComponent" defined in your "describe" here
    // because "mountedComponent" is pass by value
    mountedComponent = mount(<MyComponent {...props} />);
  }
  return mountedComponent;
};

describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
  let props;
  let state;
  let mountedComponent; // This stays undefined
  // ...
}
```

Comment: The reason I use `mountedComponent`, is to be able to reset it in `beforeEach`, because I actually have lots of tests running here. Agreed, for a single test it isn't useful.

Since mountedComponent ends up referring to a React component, which is an object, I was expecting it to be passed by reference if you call the function again, is that incorrect?

Comment: @FlorianBienefelt I see, I'll remove that part of the answer. Initially, your variable is not an object, though, so it'll stay undefined. Even with an object, you can only modify its properties, so you can't just assign it as some new component.

Comment: @FlorianBienefelt Ignore the "Initially, your variable is not an object, though, so it'll stay undefined.". Even with an object, you are passing the value of the reference to the function. Hence, if you do `mountedComponent = foo`, you are not changing what's inside that reference but just replaced the value of the reference. It's a bit hard to explain...I hope I made a bit of sense.